# Clearing masked phone input isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, maskedinput

I have a search input with a phone masked formatting when I'm clicking the (x) to clear the input, it removes just the first number.

```
    $(function() {
       $('#phoneNumber').mask("(999) 999-9999");
   });

  <td>
   <input type="search" cssStyle="width:170px" id="phoneNumber" path="phoneNumber"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
           $("#phoneNumber").focus();
         });
    </script>
 </td>
```

if I deleted the mask, the clear will be working just fine

Comment: What are the versions for JQuery and JQuery Mask libraries?

Comment: `mask` is not a standard jquery function. If your using a plugin and it's not working, I'd suggest raising a bug on that plugin

Comment: mask version : 1.2.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.1

Comment: I'm going to try to update to the latest versions, That might be a bug I have

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what this mask plugin does, but I'm going ot suggest you get rid of it and just use some standard HTML instead.

- Use `type="tel"` instead of `type="search"` since this is for a telephone number and not for a search
- Use `autofocus` to automatically set the focus to this field instead of doing it with jQuery's `.focus()` function
- use the `placeholder` attribute instead of a jQuery library

```html
<input type="tel" autofocus placeholder="(999) 999-9999" style="width:170px"/>
```

it should work as you want, and now it requires zero JavaScript and it uses native HTML features.

Comment: Also, I still need to show the phone formatting when user insert the phone#

Comment: well the clear (X) button is a feature of the `type="search"` input.

Comment: If you open your snippet on IE, the 'x' will show up

Comment: Yeah the (x) button is something that different browsers implement differently, you should not rely on it always being there.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should update the versions to latest. But as a work around until you update JQuery to latest, just update the Mask library version to latest (1.7.7) and that should resolve your issue.

https://plugins.jquery.com/mask/